# Track changes database structure

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I work in a team where many of us connect to the same oracle database. So anyone is permitted to do any changes to the database. I want to track those changes, specifically in the table structure, indexes, primary/foreign keys etc. I want to refer this history to check what had been changed off late and by which user along with modified date. Is there a script or any way to do this? Awaiting your suggestions,
Thanks.

Comment: system level triggers can observe ddl changes I think

Comment: Look at [Configuring and Administering Auditing](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/cfgaudit.htm#BABCFIHB)

Comment: I strongly recommend you to look at what we are doing in DBmaestro (www.dbmaestro.com). Our TeamWork solution is exactly what you need.